# In Symfony2.0, I want to disable some url in router.yml when using app.php (prod env)?

Tags: php, symfony

When using app_dev.php, there are some useful url for me to debug project. Such as

```
check_debug:
    pattern: /check_url1
    defaults: {....}

check_debug_and_prod:
    pattern: /check_url2
    defaults: {....}

check_prod:
    pattern: /check_url3
    defaults: {....}
```

I want to disable 'check_debug' when I using app.php(prod env), and disable 'check_prod' when I using app_dev.php(dev env), and keep 'check_debug_and_prod' both when using app.php or app_dev.php.

How to config in SF2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple routing.yml files for different environments. E. g. `app/config/routing.yml`, `app/config/routing_dev.yml`

You can have different routing files for different environments:

1. Create `src/AAA/Bundle/CCBundle/Resource/config/routing.yml`
2. Create `src/AAA/Bundle/CCBundle/Resource/config/routing_dev.yml`
3. Include `src/AAA/Bundle/CCBundle/Resource/config/routing.yml` in `app/config/routing.yml`
4. Include `src/AAA/Bundle/CCBundle/Resource/config/routing_dev.yml` in `app/config/routing_dev.yml`

Comment: but the routing.yml in my bundle, src/AAA/Bundle/CCBundle/Resource/config/routing.yml.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `routing_dev.yml` to add routes you only want in the dev mode. When you will use `app.php` it will only check for `routing.yml` and this way you will not have to be preoccupied by the unwanted routes.

You can also create your own routing files. See how Sf2 handles to import inside yml files.